# Using a Shiro Filter on JAX-RS without Web.xml

Tags: java, web-services, rest, shiro

I am using JAX-RS and I have a rest service that I would like to secure using shiro basic auth. I currently have a class that extends Application as per the Servlet 3 spec and everything run fine. I can't seem to get Shiro basic auth filter to work and since I have no web.xml, it will not let me add a filter chain there. Is there a way to programatically add a filter in my application sub class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a web descriptor to your application. According to Servlet 3.0 specs, web.xml is optional and just extends and/or overrides your annotation configuration.

You could then define a Shiro filter in your web.xml as usual and JAX-RS related configuration will stay configured via annotations. This is a natural approach.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>configPath</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:shiro.ini</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

If it is not an option for you and you don't want web.xml to arise in your application, you could also extend from `ShiroFilter` class and provide your own annotation configurations in order to get Shiro filter chained:

```
@WebFilter(initParams = { @WebInitParam(name = "configPath", value = "classpath:shiro.ini") })
public class MyShiroFilter extends ShiroFilter {
}
```

I didn't test that code above, this is just an approach.